# Django Debug toolbar shows up, but the panels return 404

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

It was working in the last couple of days, but now all the links on the toolbar themselves are just #

```
<li class="djDebugPanelButton active">
<input type="checkbox" data-cookie="djdtSQLPanel" checked="checked" title="Disable for next and successive requests">
    <a href="#" title="SQL queries from 1 connection" class="SQLPanel">SQL<br><small>215 queries in 174.10ms</small></a>
</li>
```

I've set it up explicitly like this says:  http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/installation.html#explicit-setup

I don't get the djdt namespace issue in fact I get no errors at all, except the 404 when I try to view one of the panels.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the grunt proxy.  Since i'm working with angular for parts of this project, grunt was serving up the angular stuff and proxying the django stuff.

```
proxies: [{
    context: ['/api', '/ngforms', '/account', '/static', '/admin', '/__debug__'],
    host: '<%= yeoman.pyhost %>',
    port: '<%= yeoman.pyport %>'
}],
```

I had to add the `/__debug__` context to the grunt proxy so that DjDT could actually see the request to respond.

Comment: That's funny.  I had this exact same problem but with an nginx proxy.

Answer (score 14):

Placing:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),)
```

before all other URLs did the trick for me. Then:

```
urlpatterns += patterns(...)
```

for the rest of the URLs, like `django-cms`, etc.

Or if you prefer to place `debug_toolbar` implementation at the end of the file `urlpatterns = patterns('', url...) + urlpatterns`.